# Overriding _init function in C , how safe is it?

Tags: c, linux

I am building a debugging memory tool in a form of a shared library which I link against an executable at run time(includes overrided methods of malloc family). To handle initializations of my data structures I simple use a condition variable. Every time my malloc is called I check if the variable is not set and then I call a function responsible for initializing my structures. Now this works fine for programs running a single thread of execution but problems arise if a program includes more than 1 thread.

The only way (I can think of) to be sure that initialization happens before the user spawns any threads is to override _init as shown [in this link](http://hackerboss.com/overriding-system-functions-for-fun-and-profit/).

Now this small example runs right but when I try to override _init on my own shared libary I get this error when trying to link it :

```
memory2.o: In function `_init':
memory2.c(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crti.o(.init+0x0): 
 first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use exactly the same steps as in the example from the link, it's just that my shared library also includes a set of global variables and overrided versions of malloc/free etc.

Anyone can give me a pointer of what's going wrong? Furthermore , is there anything else to take into consideration when overriding _init ( I am guessing it's not a very normal thing to do).

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the following FAQ page:

http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#INIT-AND-CLEANUP

It describes `_init/_fini` as dangerous and obsolete, and recommends that `__attribute__ ((constructor))` and `__attribute__ ((destructor))` are used instead.

From the [`gcc` manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconstructor_007d-function-attribute-2388):

> `constructor (priority)`
>   `destructor (priority)`
>
> The
>   constructor attribute causes the
>   function to be called automatically
>   before execution enters `main()`.
>   Similarly, the destructor attribute
>   causes the function to be called
>   automatically after `main()` has
>   completed or `exit()` has been called.
>   Functions with these attributes are
>   useful for initializing data that will
>   be used implicitly during the
>   execution of the program. You may
>   provide an optional integer priority
>   to control the order in which
>   constructor and destructor functions
>   are run. A constructor with a smaller
>   priority number runs before a
>   constructor with a larger priority
>   number; the opposite relationship
>   holds for destructors. So, if you have
>   a constructor that allocates a
>   resource and a destructor that
>   deallocates the same resource, both
>   functions typically have the same
>   priority. The priorities for
>   constructor and destructor functions
>   are the same as those specified for
>   namespace-scope C++ objects (see C++
>   Attributes).
>
> These attributes are not currently
>   implemented for Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can write your own _init or main:

GNU GCC allows you to define your own function of the same name as an existing symbol.  When linking, you provide an argument of `-Xlinker --wrap=<symName>`.  Pretending you did this to main, you can call the real main via `__real_main(...)`:

```
int main(int argc, void *argv)
{
    // any code you want here
    return __real_main(argc,argv);
}
```

2) You can write your own dynamic linker.  If you do this then set the .interp section to point to the shared object containing your dynamic linker/loader.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome that error compile the code as `gcc -nostartfiles memory2.c -o memory2`, here we are skipping the constructor and destructor.

But it is not recommended to override these.